# After click on row, remove seletced class from another rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one small problem with my **JQuery** Code.

I created simple table in HTML.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name 1</td>
    <td>surname 1</td>
    <td>actions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name 2</td>
    <td>surname 3</td>
    <td>actions</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then I want to highlight the `row` in yellow, when I click on this `row`
So when I am click on `row` add class "`selected`" but when I click on another `row` I have to remove "`selected`" class from previous row. So I tried create **JQuery** action

```
$('tr').not(':first').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest("table");
    var rows = table.children("tr");
    alert(rows.length);
    rows.each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });

    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I tried find closest table from this clicked `row` and get all children `<tr>`,
next in loop remove "`selected`" class and add to clicked `row` this class.

But always `alert(rows.length)` return me 0 `row`s :<

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not simply

```
$('tr').not(':first').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("selected"); //add class selected to current clicked row
  $(this).siblings().removeClass( "selected" ); //remove class selected from rest of the rows
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove class from the selected one, then add the class to the new one.

```
$('tr').not(':first').click(function () {

    $('tr.selected').removeClass("selected");

    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's works, but when i have few tables on the site it clears all "selected "classes in all tables, I trying write one JQuery function for all tables But Thanks For answer

Comment: Right,
Now your code explained to me my mistake :)
Thanks

Comment: I think, gurvinder's answer is the best one for your case. I am still keeping my initial answer for the other case (when anyone wants to unselect from any table if a row from one table is selected.)

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
$('.table tr').not(':first').on('click', function(){
 $('.table tr').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

As per your question, write like this:

```
var rows = $(this).siblings("tr");
```

Instead of:

```
var rows = table.siblings("tr");
```

Comment: Yes, it's works, but when i have few tables on the site it clears all "selected "classes in all tables, I trying write one JQuery function for all tables

But Thanks For answer

Comment: Now I know :)
Thanks